# Allocate daily sales to date created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Im trying to gather all sales made within a week and put each sale in day made. If Moday was two sales, then `Monday => {...}, {...}` etc

"Monday" would be ruby's date format.

In my db I have 5 sale objects: Two sales on Monday and two on Tuesday.

**Controller:**

```
def daily_customer_sale(created)
  date_and_id = Sale.where('created_at >= ?', created).pluck(:created_at, :id)
  date_and_id.each do |obj|
    yield(obj.first, obj.last)
  end
end

def daily_sales(created=nil)
  sales_by_date = Hash.new(0)

  daily_customer_sale(created) do |date, id|
    s_date = date.to_date
    sales_by_date[s_date] = Sale.find(id) # Seems to return only one object per day
  end

  return sales_by_date
end
```

**For views:**

```
daily_sales(1.week.ago.to_datetime)
```

What I get in two dates (correct) in which each data has only one object when it should be two or more per date. Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need complex logic to do it. Here is a cleaner way

```
Sale.where('created_at >= ?', created_at).group_by{ |sale| sale.created_at.to_date}
```

It will return All the sales grouped by day.
`key` will be date object and for each day there will be sale array containing all of the sales for that day.

If you need `string` based key you can format it as you like as per below

```
Sale.where('created_at >= ?', created_at).group_by{ |sale| sale.created_at.to_date.to_s } #default date format

Sale.where('created_at >= ?', created_at).group_by{ |sale| sale.created_at.to_date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") } #23/09/2016
```

You can have a look at [Group by](http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/group_by) method